# Is there anyway to sync setState in react

Tags: reactjs

As we've known, setState is async. I've read few questions about setState, on how to use the value right after setState, but those aren't what I need right now.

I'm trying to set value for array List, and then use that List to do a function to get the value for Result. If setState isn't async, then it would be like this

`

```
handleChange(e) {
    const resultList = this.state.list.slice();
    resultList[e.target.id] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
      list: resultList,
      result: this.doSomething(resultList) // this.doSomething(this.state.list)
    });
  }
```

`

Is there anyway to achieve this? A documentation or keyword to research would be awesome.
Many thanks

Comment: async -> await. Look into that ;)

Comment: Thanks @FilipGrebowski, i will

Comment: It's unclear from the question what the problem is. Is it `this.doSomething(this.state.list)` that doesn't work?

Comment: @estus setState can't update the value due to async

Answer (score 1):

There is a callback parameter to setState which is called after the state has been updated

```
this.setState({
  list: resultList,
  result: this.doSomething(resultList)
}, () => {
    //do something with the updated this.state
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use async await like

```
     async handleChange(e) {
        const resultList = this.state.list.slice();
        resultList[e.target.id] = e.target.value;
       this.setState({
           list: resultList,
           result: await this.doSomething(resultList) // this.doSomething(this.state.list)
       });
    }
```

Comment: My problem isn't solved, but thanks Dasari, i will have a look on async await

Answer (score 0):

The use of `this.state` together with `this.setState` is discouraged, exactly because state updates are asynchronous and may result in race conditions.

In case updated state derives from previous state, [state updater function](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) should be used. Because it's asynchronous, event object should be treated beforehand, due to how synthetic events work in React:

```
const { id, value } = e.target;
this.setState(state => {
  const list = [...state.list];
  list[id] = value;

  return {
    list,
    result: this.doSomething(list)
  };
});
```

Comment: If i do it this way then it would catch a type Error: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

Comment: The use of `slice()` in original code suggests that it's an array. In case you expect it to be, consider providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem, because the error clearly states that it isn't an array, and you have a problem somewhere else. Any way, that's how asynchronicity of setState is treated.